# Flutter GetX Obx do not update UI automatically

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-getx

I have a screen that I'd put all body in an Obx . I have a Row like bellow

```
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
    Visibility(
      visible: !lastController.posts[i].isDownloaded,
      child: GestureDetector(
               onTap: () async {
                      lastController.isDownloading.value = true;
                      await lastController.setPostIsDownloading(i);
                      await lastController.Download(i);
                      await lastController.setPostIsDownloading(i);
                      lastController.isDownloading.value = false;
                               },
                      child: lastController.isDownloading.value?
                                lastController.posts[i].isDownloading? 
                                 SizedBox(
                                   height: 22,
                                   width: 22,
                                   child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                            value:lastController.percentage.value,
                                            ),
                                            )
                                            : const Icon(
                                                          FontAwesome.download,
                                                          color: Colors.white,
                                                        )
                                                  : const Icon(
                                                      FontAwesome.download,
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                    ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          const SizedBox(
                                            width: 10.0,
                                          ),
                                          Visibility(
                                            .....
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      )
```

and my Controller is like bellow

```
class LastMonasebatController extends GetxController {


RxList<Posts> posts = <Posts>[].obs;

Future<void> setPostIsDownloading(int id) async {
    posts[id].isDownloading = !posts[id].isDownloading;

    posts.refresh();

  }


Future<void> Download(int id) async {
    ........
    posts[id].isDownloaded = true;
    posts.refresh();
  }


}
```

When I tap on GestureDetector the post downloading until end but the icon does not change and after downloading complete when I hot reload the controller icon disappeared because post.isDownloaded is false . This is not change UI Automatically . What is the problem ?

I want Getx to change the UI automatically

Answer (score 2):

`RxList` needs a manual update when its elements changes, so it updates on `Obx`, you need to call `refresh()` on it like this:

```
Future<void> Download(int id) async {
 ........
 posts[id].isDownloaded = true;
 shabs.refresh();
 posts.refresh(); // add this
}
```

this will tell `Obx` that the `RxList` is the same object, but its inside elements did change to update.

and this is an assume, but in your code, there are two checks over `isDownloading`,

```
 // ...
 child: lastController.isDownloading.value?
     lastController.posts[i].isDownloading? 
 // ...
```

maybe you need to check only over the ones that belongs to the `posts[i]`:

```
     // ...
    child: lastController.posts[i].isDownloading? 
    // ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , it was typing problem . I edit my question . I have posts.refresh() but still UI does not update automatically

Comment: oh, I see also that in the child there are two checks on multiple different `isDownloading` variables, can you check it, maybe you wanted to check over the one which belongs to the `posts[i]` element.

Comment: thank you again . One of isDownloadin is a RxBool variable in Controller and the other one is a property of Posts Class (RxList<Posts>)

Comment: @Gwhyyy Can you help me ? I could not find any solution

Comment: can you share with me your code, so I will try it and try to fix it